# How to import android facebook sdk to simple app example?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, import

I want to make a simple Android app which connect to facebook, but i'му begin to make it and found missing pics
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android
http://developers.dev.facebook.com/attachment/app_wizard.png
http://developers.dev.facebook.com/attachment/app_properties.png

and just don't know how to import or make right compilation of Facebook source to add it as a library to "simple" example.
I'm using Intellij IDEA, but if you describe for eclipse, i'll be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262221/) that has project setup instructions and a link to the sample project with Facebook SDK.

If it doesn't help, please provide more details, however it's probably too late considering the question date.