# Unable to use android facebook sdk with android project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij seems to be detecting the sources fine, no errors in editor, but errors when I remove facebook sDK from project.

I added the facebook-android-sdk module as a module dependency to my project, but when running it, it gives 8 facebook sdk related errors:

> package com.facebook.android.Facebook does not exist cannot find
>   symbol class FacebookError

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you check the answer and sample project at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262221/ ? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import */gen and include it part of the module and it'll be all fine. Don't just import src/