# Android Facebook SDK - android.support-v4 issue (class android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found)

Tags: android, facebook, maven, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm having trouble getting the Facebook SDK (v3.7) to work in my Android Intellij project.

I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14732898/4048490) to add the Facebook library as a new module to my project , but I keep getting this error:

> java: cannot access android.support.v4.app.Fragment
>         class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found

Here is a screenshot of my module's dependencies:

[image]

And this is a screenshot of the Facebook module dependencies:
[image]

When I add the v4 support library to my own module, I get a different error:

```
Android Dex: [FunnyGific] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$1;
```

I tried using the `android-support-v4.jar` I found in the `facebook-android-sdk-3.7/facebook/libs` folder, also tried to import it via Maven and I keep getting the same errors. Any ideas here?

The *only* situation I could get it to work is by adding the Facebook mvn repository, but even in this case I'm getting some strange exception when I try to show the Facebook LoginButton (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.android.R$color`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.avianey</groupId>
    <artifactId>facebook-android-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Running out of ideas, would love some help to get this working.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out how to get this to work?

Comment: @ItzHoudini I actually switched to Eclipse, Intellij was a waste of time. It was a lot easier to manage the Facebook SDK after the switch, although there's still some funkiness with that support library. In Eclipse I just had to add the Facebook SDK jar (located in the `bin` directory) to Java Build Path > Libraries, and also add the support library to my project's `libs` folder.

Comment: Ahh. Sucks to have to switch back to eclipse after just getting started with IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue in IdeaU v14: FragmentActivity not found! 
[image]

1) Library Settings:
[image]

2) Class Path Add
[image]

3) Locate Extras>Android>Support>v4 (or whatever version you need)
[image]

4) Rejoice! red squiggles go away.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I'm using eclipse, so my steps to solve this problem using eclipse:

1. In eclipse after you import facebook sdk to your workspace; right click on FacebookSDk library then chose properties or press Alt + enter.
2. Choose "java build path" from the left panel, then go to Libraries Tab.

   [image]
3. Click "add external jars" then go to facebook sdk path or location chose libs folder add android-support-v4 file and bolts file.

Comment: thanks for sharing this, I'm looking for Intellij instructions though. I added the support-v4 library as an external library and it still gives me errors.