# Android Dex: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: already added when i rebuild the project

Tags: android, facebook, intellij-idea

i know that this problem is with libraries. In my project i want to use sign in with facebook, and i need to add facebooksdk.jar and add facebook project like library. But i get errors. I'm working in Intellij IDEA. There you can see my exceptions and project properties.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262330/104891?

Comment: Yes, and i make somethink like this, but it did not works

Comment: You don't need both `facebooksdk.jar` and `Facebook` modules in the dependencies. Use only module dependency.

Comment: java: package 
com.facebook does not exist, but i add facebook module

Comment: but in facebook library com.facebook packuage is empty

Comment: Facebook SDK module seems to be missing the sources configuration. Download the [sample project](ftp://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.idea/FacebookApiTest.zip) and compare it to your setup.